# ObjectNode (jackson.databind) a List<String>

Tags: java, json

Parseo un archivo Json con la siguiente linea empleando un ObjectNode

```
    ObjectNode fileContent = getJsonFile("ruta/archivoAParsear.json");
```

He intentado llevarmelo a una List de la siguiente manera , y no se me ocurre una manera limpia de hacerlo:

```
    List<String> content = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(fileContent.get("files").asText(), String[].class));
```

¿Ideas?

PD: Forma que tiene mi archivo JSON :

```
{
  "files":[
            "datos",
             "muchos_mas_datos"
          ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada me parece que no es correcto parsear un json a una lista de string ya que como bien indicas proviene de NODO, por lo que debe contener la jerarquía  padre e hijos.

Te sugiero cambiar el String por un Object por **ejemplo**

```
   class FileObject{
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
}
```

Luego tendrás que cambiar el string por el objeto.

```
List<FileObject> content = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(fileContent.get("files").asText(), FileObject[].class));
```

***El FileObject es un ejemplo, reemplazalo por los valores que contiene tu archivo.***

**Saludos**

Comment: Actualmente , mi solucion no funciona , no obtiene de manera correcta una Lista , por tanto , tu solucion no seria valida , aparte que no veo necesario en ningun sentido crearse una Clase con un unico atributo para este tipo de cosas.